# Sentry with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sentry

I've been using Sentry with Python 2.7, is there any problem with using Python 3 ? The documentation in the official site only refers to Sentry with Virtualenv and Pip and not Virtualenv for Python 3 and Pip3.

Answer (score 1):

The clients are version agnostic (that is, they run on anything newer than 2.5) so they don't care what version you're using for your applications. That said, the server will never run on Python 3, but it simply doesn't matter as its isolated. A bit extreme, but its kind of the same direction as "can we run the server on Ruby?"

Comment: for the curious ones, never say never! https://blog.sentry.io/2019/05/14/sentry-9-1-and-upcoming-changes or how python3 is not ruby.